# Connect Xamarin forms with Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am very new to Xamarin forms and I am trying to create an app that will connect to my existing Azure SQL database. I was trying to follow the tutorial on here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started but when it gets to download the backend, the link gives me error 404. After some more reading I found out that this method is no longer used but instead connecting it through the Visual Studio App center. So I pop on that and added all the statements from there in my code but I can't see any way of connecting this to Azure. Also, I've create the web service on Azure, where I linked my Azure SQL database. So the question now is how do I actually connect the two? I couldn't find any documentation on this so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your mobile client connects to your web services, which is extensively documented.  Your web services connect to your DB server, which is also extensively documented.  What **specifically** are you having problems with?

Comment: All the documentation and tutorials on Pluralsight I've found in connecting my mobile client with my web service seems to be old and can't recreate the steps. Is the mobile client now supposed to be just an asp.net core web api? Do you have a link maybe to an up to date documentation?

Comment: google "Xamarin web service" and you get thousands of relevant hits, including the official docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/web-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, you mentioned you already created web service to access your Azure SQL, Now you may be need to know how to access web service from Xamrin forms.

If yes, kindly follow below link for same

Here are the few references:  [Consuming asmx services in Xamarin](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asmx-services-in-xamarin-forms/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/web-service/?tabs=vswin).